# Gaining an OAuth Token from a Web Flow Login on GitHub

Tags: github, github-api, github3.py

I started to integrate GitHub3.py, and from what I have seen it appears to be an excellent library for my use.

However, I'm a little confused on how to go forward and get using the library in my Django project. So far, I have implemented a login method using the GitHub web flow API, this returns me a code which I could send to the API to return an OAuth token.

However, from reading the GitHub3.py docs, I'm not sure how this can be done.

So I'm wondering how I should go forward from here. I have read this past issue https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/issues/7 - I don't believe this applies to me since an OAuth code has a already been achieved.

I'm fairly new to Python and OAuth authentication, so I would appreciate it if somebody could push me in the right direction (if the library has code to OAuth methods or if there is another way that I am not familiar with)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you have a token for a user who has granted you permission (i.e., they logged went through the webflow and your application has received and stored the token GitHub returns).

In this case you can do the following:

```
import github3

g = github3.login(token=TOKEN_RECEIVED_FROM_THE_API)
```

With that (and assuming you have the proper scopes on the token) you should be able to use most methods that require authentication. If you have the `user` scope you can use `g.user()` to get some extra detail about the logged in user.

If you have `repos` then you can also list a user's private repositories.

In short, when we wrote the library we wanted to make it easy to authenticate in a number of ways and then use the same API that you would if you had authenticated another way.

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. I've been able to fork too after you're help with my question about the REST API :)